# How is this a specialization?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY) lecture, where the following example (@29.43) is presented as a specialization :

```
template<class T>
struct rank
{
    static const size_t value = 0u; 
}

// partial specialization
template<class U, size_t N>
struct rank<U[N]>
{
    static const size_t value = 1 + rank<U>::value; 
}
```

I would expect a compile error, complaining about the declarations of the structs being incombatible and the second one having too many template parameters. **How is the above not an error?**

Comment: It's not a specialization, just another template declaration.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Er... what? It's a specialization. You can't have multiple distinct template classes with the same name, and the code doesn't try to do that.

Comment: @doc GCC 4.8.3 gives no such error, assuming the missing semicolons are added and `<stddef.h>` is included to make `size_t` available.

Comment: @hvd clang 3.5.0: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e21938612446974 gcc 4.9.2: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/459cb07926e203e5

Comment: @doc The `rank<int, 2>` is the error, and that's something you added, not something that's in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specialisations can have template parameters themselves. Specialisations with template parameters are called partial specialisations.

```
template<class T>
struct rank { ...1 };
```

means `rank<T>` is a class, and unless otherwise specified, `...1` is the class's definition.

```
template<class U, size_t N>
struct rank<U[N]> { ...2 };
```

is the "otherwise specified": it means that if the `T` in `rank<T>` can be written as `U[N]` for some type `U` and some constant `N`, then `...2` is the class's definition.

You'd use it like `rank<int[2]>`, which would use the second class definition with `U = int` and `N = 2`.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it corrected its 2 predecessors and gave the first correct insight

Answer (score 4):

It's not an error because it's valid.

> `[C++11: 14.5.5/1]:` A primary class template declaration is one in which the class template name is an identifier. A template declaration in which the class template name is a *simple-template-id* is a partial specialization of the class template named in the *simple-template-id*. A partial specialization of a class template provides an alternative definition of the template that is used instead of the primary definition when the arguments in a specialization match those given in the partial specialization (14.5.5.1). *[..]*

There's simply no rule to prohibit it and, in fact, the standard contains an example of precisely this scenario:

> `[C++11: 14.5.5/3]:` *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T1, class T2, int I> class A { };             // #1
> template<class T, int I>            class A<T, T*, I> { };   // #2
> template<class T1, class T2, int I> class A<T1*, T2, I> { }; // #3
> template<class T>                   class A<int, T*, 5> { }; // #4
> template<class T1, class T2, int I> class A<T1, T2*, I> { }; // #5
> ```
>
> The first declaration declares the primary (unspecialized) class template. The second and subsequent declarations declare partial specializations of the primary template. *—end example ]*

The only restriction that is even marginally related is, ironically, *closer* (though not precisely) to the opposite of what you claim:

> `[C++11: 14.5.5/8]:` Within the argument list of a class template partial specialization, the following restrictions apply:
>
> - *[..]*
> - The argument list of the specialization shall not be identical to the implicit argument list of the primary template.
> - *[..]*

You would use the primary and template and partial specialisation like so:

```
int main()
{
    rank<char>   a;   // uses the primary
    rank<int[5]> b;   // uses the partial spec.
}
```

Comment: Upboat for citing the spec.  Always good to have an authoritative reference, even a slightly incomprehensible one :-)